# VS Code on Windows debugger does not work with freopen

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I found this issue, but it was closed https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112165

The problem is that VSCode can not read data from file when debugging c++ code.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. create a .cpp file
2. create a .txt with some data
3. use freopen or fopen, read data from the .txt file
4. debugging
5. the variables never change its value

Screenshots:
[image: Step4]
[image: Step5]
[image: Step6]

The value of T was supposed to be 3 (which it is under regular execution) but under debugging it is a random value 16.

Everything is default

```
launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

I use

```
#ifdef SHERAJ
    freopen("input.txt"  , "r", stdin);
#endif
```

for competitive programming and VS Code on Mac debugger runs this perfectly fine. Please let me know a fix for this because I recently switched from Mac to Windows.

Comment: Are you sure `cwd` is correct in your launch.json?

Comment: `cwd` is auto generated. Anyways I browsed and `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin` exists. Everything works fine in debugger, only when freopen is not used.

Comment: But I would expect `cwd` to be set to the directory where `input.txt` is.

Comment: Wow, I changed `cwd` and it worked! I can't thank you enough @ssbssa

Comment: I am new to posting questions on stackoverflow and am really amazed at how helpful it is. I am curious, why did you help me @ssbssa, what's in it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Okay, I get what is happening here. In the launch.json file, the "cwd" value is the path of the current working directory of the process being launched or debugged, this is where the input files are read from and output files and written to by default.

> You should set it to the directory where the files you are working with are located.

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66049388/4115947). Similar question: [freopen() does not read / write to existing file, niether creates new file in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66049139/freopen-does-not-read-write-to-existing-file-niether-creates-new-file-in-vs)